# Search keyword from a list (in a file) and return full path

Tags: powershell, batch-file, search, export

I have a flatfile with a list of keywords. I could format this file however it is needed.

I want to search for the keyword on the server and I would like the script to return all paths that contains that keyword to a file. A full path + filename would be even better.

I need to find images on a fully loaded server and it takes 30-60 seconds per search. We need to find about 1000 keywords. So if I could get a script that will search everything and report it to an excel file for example it would be such a time saver.

Example of my flatfile

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
```

Example of desired output file:

```
Product1    c:\products\collection1\season2\product1.psd
Product1    c:\products\collection2\season3\product1-back.psd
Product1    c:\products\collection1\rejected\front-product1.txt
Product2    c:\products\collection3\season1\product2-back.pdf
Product3    c:\products\collection2\season4\product3-new.tif
```

P.S. The returned path will be UNC paths like `\\server\products\collection`

Comment: Why do you have both `powershell` and `batch-file` tags which are totally different things (although you can embed both in each other)?

Comment: I added both powershell and batch-file because I didn't care the method for the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then write it out completely and make an object to track results:

```
$searchWords = gc c:\filename.txt 
$results = @()
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    $files = gci -path C:\products -filter "*$sw*" -recurse | select FullName

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $object = New-Object System.Object
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name SearchWord –Value $sw
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name FoundFile –Value $file
        $results += $object
    }

}

$results | Export-Csv result.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Excellent! You save my day

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean?

```
gc filename.txt | % {gci -path c:\products -filter "*$_*" -recurse} | select FullName | Export-Csv result.csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: Its superb! Works exactly like I intended. The only thing that would make it even more effective is if I could have the name of the keyword in the output file before the path like:

product1, path